# Is "shouldn't" closest in meaning to "shall not" or "ought not"?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I have written this statement:

*If he yells at you again then don't put up with it, ok? You **shouldn't** be afraid to stand up to him.*

I'm not sure how **shouldn't** will be perceived here.

1) Is **shouldn't** closest in meaning to "shall not" or "ought not" here?

I don't want the latter. I could have written "don't be afraid to stand up to him" but thought it would be repetitive to use "don't" again. And using "shall not" would not be natural, would it?

2) Is "you shouldn't be afraid to stand up to him" the same as "don't be afraid to stand up to him" or is it not as strong in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I think most English speakers will perceive it as "ought not", but I also think it has the desired connotations, based on your description.  Strictly speaking, "You shouldn't be afraid..." is slightly weaker than "Don't be afraid...", but only because the latter is a direct command, while the former is a recommendation.  In this context, I think they will be perceived nearly equivalently.

The construction "You shall not be afraid..." sounds...biblical.  It's an uncommon assertion of the emotional reaction, as opposed to a command or advice.  It sounds unnatural because most speakers will assume it's a faulty prediction (the loud guy is really scary, after all) or a weak attempt at persuasion (stand up to him, don't worry, it's not that scary).